# ORA-00947: not enough values but check the column already.

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, insert-into, ora-00947

I've created a table as fllow:

```
CREATE TABLE"COMMODITY"
(COM_NO VARCHAR2(10)  NOT NULL,
COM_NAME VARCHAR2(100) NOT NULL,
SHOP_NO VARCHAR2(10)NOT NULL,
FRU_NO VARCHAR2(10)NOT NULL,
COM_PRICE NUMBER(10)NOT NULL,
COM_WEIGHT VARCHAR2(30)NOT NULL,
COM_REMARKS CLOB NOT NULL,
COM_PIC1 BLOB,
COM_PIC2 BLOB,
COM_PIC3 BLOB,
COM_TIME TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
COM_STATUS VARCHAR2(10) NOT NULL,
COM_STORE NUMBER(10) NOT NULL,
COM_SCORE NUMBER(2,1)NOT NULL,
COM_PEO NUMBER(10)NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT COM_COM_NO_PK PRIMARY KEY (COM_NO),
CONSTRAINT COM_SHOP_NO_FK FOREIGN KEY  (SHOP_NO) REFERENCES SHOP(SHOP_NO),
CONSTRAINT COM_FRU_NO_FK FOREIGN KEY  (FRU_NO) REFERENCES FRUIT(FRU_NO)
);
```

AND the sequence is

```
CREATE SEQUENCE COM_NO_SEQ
INCREMENT BY 1
START WITH 1
NOMAXVALUE
NOCACHE
NOCYCLE;
```

I'm trying to do the following:

```
INSERT INTO COMMODITY VALUES('COM'||LPAD(TO_CHAR(COM_NO_SEQ.NEXTVAL),7,'0'),'平安蘋果','SHO0000001','FRU0000001',1200,'一箱約1斤','好吃的蘋果喔我是CLOB','24-6月-17 03.22.39','上架',80,0,0);
```

I gave the value to all the column where is NOT NULL.But still have the problem of ORA-00947: not enough values.

Plz tell me why ?

Comment: Why do think you only have to supply not-null columns when not giving a column list? How does Oracle know which columns you are skipping? What if you did supply one of the nullable ones, but not the others - how could it know what you meant?

Answer (score 2):

You should provide column names in the insert statement as shown in the following example. If you don't provide a list of columns to map the values, Oracle expects values for all columns of the table.

> If you omit the column list altogether, then the values_clause or query must specify values for all columns in the table
>   [INSERT Staement](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_9014.htm#i2080498)

```
SQL> create table tt1 (id number not null, name varchar2(20));

Table created.

SQL> insert into tt1 values('Joe');
insert into tt1 values('Joe')
            *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00947: not enough values


SQL> insert into tt1 values(1);
insert into tt1 values(1)
            *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00947: not enough values


SQL> insert into tt1(id) values(1);

1 row created.
```